# Selenium grid not able to detect remote firefox driver binary after setting System.setProperty

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I am using selenium `selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0` and `geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64` for selenium grid testing.

even after setting `system.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path to firefox binary")` it is giving me following error:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path to\\geckodriver.exe");   
  DesiredCapabilities desiredCapablities= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  desiredCapablities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);   
_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(remoteUrl),desiredCapablities);
```

Exception: 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;

Comment: Exception: 

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property;

Comment: The property "webdriver.gecko.driver" is meant to define the path to `geckodriver.exe` and not `firefox.exe`. Moreover, the remote server runs on  a different JVM with a different set of properties, so you can't set this property with the client.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the driver path while launch the selenium grid node like,

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="driverpath" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0 -role node -hub http://gridip:port/grid/register
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have already tried it. I am using two different machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the geckodriver.exe to the same directory that you are running the grid from.

You should not have to set the path when creating the remote driver for firefox.